# Altering a particular column in a CSV with python3

Tags: csv, python-3.x

An example. I have a CSV file laid out as such:

```
10,20,30,-40,50
20,30,40,-50,60
30,40,50,-60,70
```

Basically I need to flip the sign of the numbers in a column. Any column. In this example the signs of the 4th and 5th...

```
10,20,30,40,-50
20,30,40,50,-60
30,40,50,60,-70
```

And print them to a new file.

I can read in a CSV file, but honestly I have no idea where to go from there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Read in the file line by line, and split by the CSV delimiter. The order of the resulting list will be in the order of the columns (ie. splitline[0] is your first csv column, etc.). You can then write that line to a new file and modify the data accordingly. In your case I believe you want the last two value multiplied by negative 1.

Comment: In your example you have the last two columns negated. Do you want then swapped instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `csv` lib to parse your file:

```
import csv


with open("in.csv") as f, open("new.csv","w") as tmp:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    wr = csv.writer(tmp)
    # wr.writerow(next(r))  #  uncomment if file has header
    # (*_ -> all but last two),  (a, b  -> second last and last value)
    #  -- == +,  -+ == -
    wr.writerows(_ + [-int(a), -int(b)]  for *_, a, b in r:)
```

Input:

```
10,20,30,-40,50
20,30,40,-50,60
30,40,50,-60,70
```

Output:

```
10,20,30,40,-50
20,30,40,50,-60
30,40,50,60,-70
```

If you want the nth columns just change how you unpack:

```
wr.writerows([a, b, c , -int(d), -int(e)] + _ for a, b, c, d, e,*_ in r:)
                         ^^       ^^
                         4th       5th

wr.writerows([-int(a),b, -int(c), d, e] + _ for a, b, c, d, e,*_ in r:)
                     ^^       ^^
                    1st       3rd
```

If you have 41 columns and want to alter,33,39,40,41:

```
with open("in.csv") as f, open("out.csv","w") as tmp:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    wr = csv.writer(tmp)
    for *_, t_3, a, b, c, d, e, t_9, ft_0, ft_1 in r:
        wr.writerow(_ + [-int(t_3), a,  b, c, d, e, -int(t_9), -int(ft_0), -int(ft_1)])
```

Comment: This is how I've been trying to get it. The thing that's been stumping me is that I need to be able to define what column it is (The actual csv is much longer and contains private info which is why I didnt post it)

Comment: How do you mean  *define what column it is*, your question said the last two columns. Edit your question with  a more realistic example input if it is more involved than what you currently have but really unless you are saying you have no idea what column it is then this code will work

Comment: @user2036101, I see nothing in your edit that would make this code fail

Comment: No, you're correct. I had a mind lapse and didnt write it properly. However now It's inserting blank rows between each column. The only part i modified was:  


`wr.writerow(next(r))
    for *_,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i in r:
         wr.writerow(_+[-float(a),-float(b),c,d,e,f,g,h,-float(i)])
move(tmp.name, "out.csv")`

Comment: Forget the move and use the edited code, I only suggested the original answer as I thought you wanted to modify the original file. How many actual columns in the file

Comment: 41 columns. And I need to modify the 33, 39, 40 and 41 columns

Comment: Is 41 the last column?

Comment: It is the last column.

Comment: @user2036101, I added the exact code, your `wr.writerow(_+[-float(a),-float(b),c,d,e,f,g,h,-float(i)])` based on the columns being 33,39,40 and 41 was incorrect